# What is the difference between proxy_buffer and fastcgi_buffer?

Tags: configuration, nginx

I inherited an nginx config and I'm trying to optimise it for security, speed, and/or maintainability by removing rules/directives which are superfluous or not doing anything.

With this in mind, inside my `server {...}` directive, I have:

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
fastcgi_buffers 256 32k;
```

and nested within, I have individual rules for `locations {...}`, which have things like:

```
location ~ /(my|path)/ {
    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers     256 4k;
    ...
}
```

and

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fastcgi.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    ...
}
```

Behind *nginx* we have *php-fpm* with the socket described above, but we don't proxy any other http servers (no tomcat, apache, etc).

From my understanding, the `proxy_buffers` directives apply when you're proxying an http service such as apache, tomcat, or a third party website and would **not** be applicable to *php-fpm* with *fastcgi*.

And conversely, `fastcgi_buffers` is used when you **are** proxying a dynamic language engine (or whatever they're called) such as *php-fpm*, *unicorn*, or *passenger*.

Am I correct in these assumptions? And if this is the case, as I'm **not** using anything like apache or tomcat, then I could remove the `proxy_buffer*` directives as they're not being utilised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumptions are mostly correct. However there are plenty of times where `proxy_` directives would be used when placing nginx in front of an application, notably if you're running `rails` via `thin`, or any sort of Jetty-based Java application.

But you are right — in your given configuration (`fastcgi_pass`), the `fastcgi_buffer` is what you're after.

Note that the `fastcgi_buffering` wasn't full removable until nginx >= 1.5.6. Also note that both `fastcgi_buffering` and `proxy_buffering` can be disabled on a per-request basis via the `X-Accel-Buffering: no` header.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of directives would you use for rails with a `proxy_*` directive and under what conditions?